# Внедрение зависимостей в контроллерах Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Код для примера

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, Product $product, $id)
    {
        dd(
            $request->all(),
            $product->findOrFail($id),
            $id
        );
    }
}
```

Маршрут:

```
Route::get('test/{id}', 'TestController@index');
```

Вызов метода:

```
app()->call([new App\Http\Controllers\TestController, 'index'], ['id' => 1]);
```

`$id` берется с строки запроса, тут понятно. Но как в фреймворке работает внедрение зависимостей в метод. Откуда приложение знает что мне нужно передать объект класса `Request` и `Product`? Как это работает в *Laravel* и как реализовать такой функционал на чистом *PHP*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использует паттерн внедрения зависмостей, берется из контейнера

Используется [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionclass.php) для определения параметров

[Контейнер](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container) [Классы иницилизации контейнера](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers)

Comment: спасибо, теперь уже я понял куда копать дальше. здесь https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/README.html я смотрел на паттерны но такого не нашел.

Comment: @Arendach https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/DependencyInjection/README.html

Comment: о внедрении зависимостей я наслышан. я не понимал именно как приложение знает какую именно зависимость мне передать в метод

Comment: Проще говоря я не знал про рефлексию